# Vue: Trying to get a dropdown for an address state to autocomplete in Chrome

Tags: vue.js, autofill

I am trying to get the dropdown to autocomplete.  I have a saved address in Chrome but the only field that is not autocompleting is the dropdown for state.
The options are listing correctly but it's just not autocompleting it.

```js
export default {
        data() {
            return {
               selectedState: null,
               states: [
                    {label: 'California', code: "CA"},
                    {label: 'New York', code: "NY"},
               ]
            }
        }
```

```html
<select name="state" autocomplete="state">
    <option
        v-for="state in states" v-bind:value="selectedState">
        {{ state.label }}
      </option>
</select>
```

Comment: You're missing a closing single-quote after `'New York`

Comment: @Phil thanks!  missed it when copying it over to here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like this

```html
<select v-model="selectedState" name="state" autocomplete="address-level1">
  <option disabled value="">Select a state</option>
  <option v-for="state in states" :key="state.code" :value="state.code">
    {{ state.label }}
  </option>
</select>
```

According to [these docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/autocomplete#Values), the `autocomplete` value you want for state is **"`address-level1`"**.

This will bind the selected state code to your `selectedState` model.

---

If you want to bind the entire state model (eg `{ code, label }`) to `selectedState`, use `:value="state"` instead.

In testing, I found this did **not** play well with the auto-fill feature.

See https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Select

Comment: thanks Phil.  I tried this and the dropdown still stays on the first option of the array while the rest of the input fields autocomplete.  I checked in Chrome under "Manage Addresses" to ensure I have a state saved in the address, which I do ("California").

Comment: Ah, you're talking about Chrome's auto **fill**. I'll have to experiment with this to see what's going on

Comment: @burtonLowel I've updated my answer. Using `autocomplete="state"` does not work for me either but `autocomplete="address-level1"` does